# How can add bootstrap in ionic3 slider option(introduction page)

Tags: ionic-framework, bootstrap-4, ionic3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working on ionic 3 with slider option(introduction page), in that i need to add a effect as "fade" using bootstrap. Is there any way to add bootstrap in ionic.

If possible to install, then how to do?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: the ion-slide already have the effect fade.  Possible values are: slide, fade, cube, coverflow or flip.

Comment: anyway yes its possible see this link ->https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVdn8zd7eiA